# Ошибка в терминале macOS: mysql not found

Tags: mysql, sql, macos

Доброго времени суток всем,

я начал читать книгу "Изучаем SQL" Алана Бьюли. А книга ориентирована на MySQL. И естественно я решил установить на мой макбук самую новую версию MySQL. И после установки MySQL Community Server 8.1.0 Innovation с официальной страницы [MySQL:: Download MySQL Community Server](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/). Я довольный захожу в терминал и ввожу команду `mysql -V`. Как вы думаете, что мне ответил терминал? Конечно же `mysql not found`.
Помогите разобраться, что нужно сделать, чтоб заработал MySQL в терминале macOS?

Comment: Говорят, есть разница между командами ОС на запуск приложения с некими опциями командной строки, и SQL-запросами, выполняемыми в уже запущенном клиенте командной строки..

Comment: Не делайте ответ в самом вопросе. Опубликуйте его как положено, отдельно.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, хорошо завтра переделаю, спасибо))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось все просто - терминал не знает, где найти эту команду. Как это проверить - нужно задать вопрос `which mysql`. Получите ответ: `mysql not found`. Знаете, я около часа вводил в поисковик гугла запрос в разных вариациях, но с одним и тем же смыслом: "как заставить терминал макбука понять команду `mysql`?". Да, нашел одну статью, где было сказано: "найдите скрытый файл .bash_profile и пропишите туда `export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"`. Я так и сделал, прописал и сохранил файл, перезапустил терминал, ввел опять команду `which mysql` и снова терминал выдал `mysql not found`. Как так, все же сделано верно? А оказалось опять все просто - нужно все это делать с помощью самого терминала:

1. В пользовательской директории водим команду `echo $PATH`, она покажет все приоритетные директории. Как вы уже догадались, пути к `mysql` не было.
2. Чтобы узнать путь к mysql нужно ввести: `ls /usr/local/mysql/bin`. Среди множества программ Вы найдете и нужную `mysql`.
3. Здесь нужно отдать должное той статье, где было сказано ввести в файл .bash_profile строку `export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"`. Это действительно так. Но чтобы все заработало, нужно прочесть информацию в файле командой `source .bash_profile`.
4. Если еще раз ввести команду `echo $PATH`, то на первом месте приоритетных директорий вы увидите путь `/usr/local/mysql/bin:`. Это означает, что терминал теперь знает, где искать команду `mysql`.
5. И в заключении вводим в терминале `mysql -u root -p`. `-u root` говорит о том, какому пользователю предоставить доступ, Пользователю "root", т.е. суперпользователю. `-p` означает, что перед тем как предоставить доступ, обязательно нужно запросить пароль. Вводим пароль суперпользователя, и "ву а ля" терминал пишет заветные слова "Welcome to the MySQL monitor.", мне предоставляется доступ к `mysql>`.

Надеюсь моя статья поможет всем новичкам в мире реляционных баз данных.

Comment: Удивительно, но если загуглить то можно понять что ответ давно уже есть: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577374/mysql-command-not-found-in-os-x-10-7

Comment: Рад за тебя, что ты знаешь хорошо английский 

Comment: И тебе бы поучиться не помешает) Чтобы не создавать бессмысленные топики))0)

Comment: @YaMus, а с чего ты взял, что я не знаю язык )) ко всему прочему я писал, что искал в Гугле инфу, но мне эта страница на английскую версию stackiverflow не попалась. 
Также не будет лишним иметь ответ на вопрос и в русской версии.